# Gap between upper view and top cell of table view

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch

Does anybody know why there is a gap between the bottom of the view and the top of the table view? They are directly touching each other, there are no constraint errors or anything in this particular view so why would it be doing this?

[image]

Comment: Which method are you using...Auto Resizing or Auto Layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced the same problem.

Try with these:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;//It works for me
```

OR

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, 0.01f)];
```

OR

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-36, 0, 0, 0);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you haven't explicitly given the height constraint to the table view (specially if you are setting constraints from a bottom to top approach). Also, define a constraint for vertical spacing between the table view and the upper view. You will have to keep the height of at least one of the view's variable depending from what approach you have chosen to set the constraints.

Thanks.